# Reload signal for UWSGI when using Supervisord?

Tags: uwsgi, supervisord

I have been using UWSGI behind Nginx and I've set supervisord to restart the Nginx and UWSGI instances in case of a server reboot.

I am debugging my application and sometimes need to reload the application. According to [this page](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/uWSGISignals) I should be sending SIGHUP in order to do a graceful reload.

I could find a stopsignal config setting on [this page](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html), but I couldn't find any entry related to something like "reloadsignal" or "restartsignal".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

```
stopsignal

    The signal used to kill the program when a stop is requested. 
    This can be any of TERM, HUP, INT, QUIT, KILL, USR1, or USR2.

    Default: TERM

    Required: No.

    Introduced: 3.0
```

`stopsignal=HUP` is what you're looking for:

```
[program:uwsgi]
user = uwsgi
command=/usr/sbin/uwsgi ...
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile = /var/log/uwsgi/err.log
stdout_logfile = /var/log/uwsgi/out.log
stopsignal=HUP
```

Comment: When I test this, it said my UWSGI process is "stopped", not running or restarted. Besides, pressing "stop" button and expecting a reload? Doesn't make that much sense. But, thanks for the effort :)

Answer (score 1):

I've reported an issue on this [here](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/146), I hope it will be accepted as a feature request and we all have the chance to use that power.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `supervisorctl status` you'll see the pid of the uwsgi process. Something like this,

```
$ supervisorctl status
uwsgi                           RUNNING    pid 25700, uptime 0:15:48
```

All you need to do is send HUP signal manually to this pid.

```
kill -HUP 25700
```

You can automated it by,

```
supervisorctl status signal | grep -o 'pid\s\+\d*'| awk '{print $2}' | xargs -n 1  kill -HUP
```

Answer (score -1):

After using this supervisorctl status signal | grep -o 'pid\s+\d*'| awk '{print $2}' | xargs -n 1  kill -HUP for graceful reload Nginx was not being able to get connection from upstream